# Linux Package installation in Kubernetes pods

Tags: installation, package, airflow, kubernetes-pod

I am running airflow pods and I am facing issue with installing package in pod

When I exec into a pod, I cannot run the following command

```
ps aux | grep airflow
```

Then

I used

```
apt-get update && apt-get install procps
```

but it is throwing this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Any ideas to resolve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To use `apt-get` in linux, you need the `root` access, and almost all the airflow images create a new user to remove this access from the docker image in order to avoid the problems, so to solve this problem, you can create a custom image and install whatever you need.

Assume you are using the official docker image `apache/airflow`

```
FROM apache/airflow
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install procps
USER airflow
```

Then you need to build the image to use it directly if you are working in localhost, or to push it to a docker registry (docker hub for ex), then configure your server to use it.